# Angular autocomplete returns an empty field when clicked searched option

Tags: html, angular

The problem is that when i search a list of users by typing characters into the `input` field and `mat-autocomplete` finds the searched user, after i click on it to select that user the `input` field becomes empty instead of showing the selected user.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<div class="material-input">
      <mat-form-field class="form-group">
        <input id="userNameInput" matInput placeholder="Search user name" formControlName="userName" for="search-box"
          #searchBox id="search-box" (input)="search(searchBox.value)" [matAutocomplete]="auto">
        <mat-autocomplete autoActiveFirstOption #auto="matAutocomplete">
          <mat-option *ngFor="let username of mockLdap | async" [value]="username">
            {{username.userName}}
          </mat-option>
        </mat-autocomplete>
      </mat-form-field>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please read the documentation: https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/overview#setting-separate-control-and-display-values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the `[value]="username.userName"` of your option accordingly.

```
<div class="material-input">
      <mat-form-field class="form-group">
        <input id="userNameInput" matInput placeholder="Search user name" formControlName="userName" for="search-box"
          #searchBox id="search-box" (input)="search(searchBox.value)" [matAutocomplete]="auto">
        <mat-autocomplete autoActiveFirstOption #auto="matAutocomplete">
          <mat-option *ngFor="let username of mockLdap | async" [value]="username.userName">    <!--- Here you have to set username.UserName -->
            {{username.userName}}
          </mat-option>
        </mat-autocomplete>
      </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

Comment: Damn i didnt notice i missed that out it works now, thanks a lot!